# what is client side and server side programing

Tags: jsp

is it really necessary to write code in JSP in client side and handle request with servlets?

i m little confuse with server side and client side programing , i think that

("client side is side where page is lode that can program in any language such as HTML and can use CSS javascript etc and server side is one which handle request coming from client via GET & POST method in HTML and these can handle by servlets ")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JSP is not a client side language. It's a server side language which can be used to generate client side code. HTML, CSS and JS are client side languages. JSP runs on the webserver upon a HTTP request, produces HTML/CSS/JS code and the webserver sends it along with the HTTP response to the webbrowser (the client) which in turn runs HTML/CSS/JS.

A servlet is meant to preprocess/postprocess HTTP requests using normal Java code before displaying the results in a JSP.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Comment: Your description "It's a server side language which can be used to generate client side code" makes lot of sense.